# How to include a included header file from one project to another? VS2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, header-files

I have a project called Configurationhandler, and I have included a header file xerces\DomParser.hpp in Configurationhandler.h

And ConfigurationHandler.h is included in HouseKeeper.h. But when I try to build, the ConfigurationHandler builds without errors, but HouseKeeper project gives an error saying it can't find the file.
 EDIT: Both projects are within the same solution.

Comment: How are you including `ConfigurationHandler.h` in the `HouseKeeper.h` file? Is the `ConfigurationHandler` project and the `HouseKepper` project within the same solution?

Comment: Yes, both projects are within the same solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming HouseKeeper is a different project, you'll need to add the path to the directory containing ConfigurationHandler.h into your HouseKeeper project settings..

I don't have VS2008 handy, but on VS2005, it would be:

- Right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer
- Select properties
- Under Configuration Properties\C/C++\General you should see 'Additional Include Directories' - add the path in here

Comment: Does it not inherit from the parent projects?

Comment: It would do if you've setup Houskeeper to be a nested project under Configurationhandler, which I suspect you probably haven't done. Just because they both belong to the same solution, and one includes the other, doesn't make it a child..

Comment: How do I make it a nested project, just change the build order?

Comment: Its not something I've ever done personally, but you should be able to find plenty of info on how to do it by googling e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164696(v=vs.80).aspx